# Dividing a cell in a table

Tags: html, html-table, cell, divide

I need to divide a cell in such a way that it has 1 title on top, and 2 below it in html without disrupting the rest of the table. [table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShIAw.png)

I've tried doing a nested table, and playing around with colspan and rowspan, but I'm new at this and haven't gotten it right.

Comment: Check out `rowspan` and `colspan`, but if you're trying to create a layout, use `display: grid` instead. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_table_colspan_rowspan.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use this following code for showing that style on the table:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
   table,th,td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse:collapse;
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="600">
 <caption>Student's Info</caption>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" width="20%">Name</th>
   <th rowspan="2" width="20%">Class</th>
   <th colspan="2" width="30%">Parents</th>
   <th rowspan="2" width="30%">Roll No.</th>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Father</th>
    <th>Mother</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td colspan="2">X and Y</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td colspan="2">F and G</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
 </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[

```css
table,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 600px
}

th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td,
th {
    text-align: center;

}

td {
    padding: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;

}

th {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
   
  </head>
  <body>
 
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">N.</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Course Code</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Course Name</th>
            <th colspan="3">Number of hours</th>
            <th rowspan="2">pre-course</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Actions</th>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <th>practical</th>
            <th>theoritical</th>
            <th>credit</th>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>1.</td>
            <td>Societal issues</td>
            <td>UNV101</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>there is no..</td>
            <td>ــ</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>2.</td>
            <td>Societal issues</td>
            <td>UNV101</td>

            <td>3.</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>there is no..</td>
            <td>ــ</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>3.</td>
            <td>Societal issues</td>
            <td>UNV101</td>

            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>there is no..</td>
            <td>ــ</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>2.</td>
            <td>Societal issues</td>
            <td>UNV101</td>

            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>there is no..</td>
            <td>ــ</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>5.</td>
            <td>Societal issues</td>
            <td>UNV101</td>

            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>there is no..</td>
            <td>ــ</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>6.</td>
            <td>Societal issues</td>
            <td>UNV101</td>

            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>there is no..</td>
            <td>ــ</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>7.</td>
            <td>Societal issues</td>
            <td>UNV101</td>

            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>there is no..</td>
            <td>ــ</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

[][1][1](https://www.mediafire.com/view/ref7g34mvq2ne64/table.png/file)

[1](https://www.mediafire.com/view/ref7g34mvq2ne64/table.png/file):[table of dividing header](https://www.mediafire.com/view/ref7g34mvq2ne64/table.png/file)